# how do you block access to my site from any IP address other than mine

Tags: ip, block

I have a staging site I do not want anyone to view except for me. I thought I had it blocked, but I found the staging site live while searching. I want to block all IPs except my IP from seeing the staging site.

I have tried the no follow in robots.txt

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to implement this.

(a) Protect your site temporary using password until you release to production.

(b) Protect your site by IP address in server side scripting to allow access by your own IP address only.

(c) Protect your site by IP address in firewall to allow access by own IP address.